# Get Image from File - Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, gdi+

I try to load an image fro ma file. Here's my code:

```
public static Image GetImageFromFile(string filePath)
{
    using (var src = Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
        var target = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, src.PixelFormat);
        target.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);

        using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            canvas.DrawImageUnscaled(src, 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height);
        }       

        return target;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error message (Out of memory) in line

```
canvas.DrawImageUnscaled(src, 0, 0, src.Width, src.Height);
```

but when I move

```
target.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);
```

after using statements, everything works well.

Could you please tell me why? I thought that I should set resolution before draw image?

Here are my platform and code details:

- Platfrom: x86.
- .Net Framework 4.0
- src.Width: 7360
- src.Height: 4912
- src.PixelFormat: Format24bppRgb
- src.HorizontalResolution : 300
- src.VerticalResolution:  300

UPDATE:
If I run this code in for loop I'm still get an error message = out of memory exception. Do you have any idea how can I handle this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I've forgotten to add it. I've just updated my post. target.HorizontalResolution and target.VerticalResolution  are the same (I would like to use only once this line of code)/

Comment: It has changed, but I'm getting an error when I run SetResolution before using statements. I need have a resolution according to the source image.

Comment: What is the value of `target.HorizontalResolution` and `target.VerticalResolution` both before and after the `target.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);` line?

Comment: Before: target.HorizontalResolution and target.VerticalResolution equals 96, and after the variables equals  300.

Comment: Why do you want 300 DPI on a screen rather than 96 DPI? _300 DPI is more common for printing than display._

Comment: It depends because it should be the same as a source image resolutions. Once it can be 96 and otherwise 300.

Comment: If you comment out `target.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);` what doesn't work **exactly**? Does it not display the way you expect? Something else?

Comment: It works (the resolution is 96), but I'm curious why the app throws error when I use SetResolutions before using statement.